# How to clear system memory after BeginReceive() and EndReceive() function?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets

I am doing a project where I am connecting to an USSD server using socket. This project is a scheduler which runs real time and 24/hrs.

Below is my code for `BeginReceive()` and `EndReceive()`

```
Public Sub Receive(ByVal client As Socket)

    Dim state As New StateObject
    state.workSocket = client

    Try

        If m_clientSocket.Connected Then

             client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), state)
         Else
             Connect()
         End If

    Catch se As SocketException

        logstr = se.Message
        write_log(logstr, "Receive", "Receive")

    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub ReceiveCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)

    Dim state       As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
    Dim client      As Socket      = state.workSocket
    Dim receiveData As String      = ""
    Dim sendData    As String      = ""

    Dim bytesRead   As Integer     = client.EndReceive(ar)

    If bytesRead > 0 Then

        state.sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead))

        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), state)      

        receiveData = state.sb.ToString()

        Me.lsBulk.Items.Insert(0, receiveData)
        sendData = getReply(receiveData)
        write_log(Now.ToString & " : " & receiveData & vbCrLf, "bytesRead", "bytesRead")

        Try

            Dim objData As [Object] = sendData
            Dim byData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString())
            If m_clientSocket IsNot Nothing Then
                m_clientSocket.Send(byData)
            End If

            write_log(Now.ToString & " : " & sendData & vbCrLf, "sendData", "sendData")

        Catch se As SocketException

            logstr = se.Message
            write_log(logstr, "WaitForData", "waitfordata")

        End Try

    Else

        receiveData = state.sb.ToString()

        If receiveData <> "" Then

            write_log(Now.ToString & " : " & receiveData & vbCrLf, "receiveData2", "receiveData2")

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is this program is taking so much of my memory. After running for the first time it takes 3.5GB then after an hour it takes 4.5GB and so on until or unless we restart it. It is becoming a big trouble for the server as it is allocating a lot of space in the memory.

I can't understand at which point I have to clear the buffer to release the system memory. The data in the buffer is not necessary to hold as every time it is writing to database.

I would like to mention that the buffer size here is 10024 every time.

Comment: @HansPassant the link you mentioned here is also mine. Actually there I asked about BeginReceive() and EndReceive() but still my problem is not solved so I am trying to open a new question with specific topic and question to get the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell the problem is you're constantly appending text into your `StringBuilder` instance and never releasing it. Your buffer is fine because it's just re-using already-allocated memory.

You can clear a StringBuilder simply by setting `sb.Length = 0`. It's a weird API in my opinion, I feel there should be a `.Clear()` method.

As I read through your code I wasn't sure why exactly you have a StringBuilder instance. What does it do elsewhere? What is the definition of `StateObject`?

Comment: Surely the StringBuilder will be collected. Since the OP has not mentioned any real issues, its just sounds like the OP doesn't understand ManagedMemory.

Comment: @Dai I am using StateObject to get the result state of AsyncState.